# Turn off animation, modal, angular-ui

Tags: angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

Is it possible to turn off the animation for the modal directive in angular-ui? http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Can't find any in the options. Should I modify the source? Or is there any best practice when you want to customize?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Currently, the bootstrap classes are embedded in the directive and need to be overridden. If you want to prevent that vertical 'drift' into position of the modal window, place the following 2 classes in your css :

```
.modal.fade {
  opacity: 1;
}

.modal.fade .modal-dialog, .modal.in .modal-dialog {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate(0, 0);
  transform: translate(0, 0);
}
```

What you would be accomplishing here is the negation of the existing translations. Not ideal, however will do the trick.

Comment: should be the same, but override .model-backdrop.fade

Comment: can also use backdrop: false in options while creating modal

Answer (score 19):

animation (Type: `boolean`, Default: `true`) - Set to `false` to disable animations on new modal/backdrop. Does not toggle animations for modals/backdrops that are already displayed.

```
var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
  animation: false
```

Comment: Thanks this is the best solution

Comment: @Worthy7 Which version are  you using ?

Comment: @MuhammedAthimannil 0.12.1 (gotta support IE8)
FYI, the slowness of the modal (even with a few css hacks) is no where near as fast as I want, changing page entirely (within angular) is faster than loading a modal

Comment: @Worthy7 You mean `AngularJS 0.12.1` ?

Answer (score 7):

An easy way to turn off the animation is to add **!important** styles to the modal.

### For all Modals

You can do that globally for all the modals with this CSS class (put it anywhere in your css):

```
.modal {
   top: 25% !important;
   opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

It will eliminate the "slide from top" animation and also the opacity animation. Personally I prefer to only eliminate the first and use only **top: 25% !important;**

You can also eliminate the backdrop animation **globally** using this class (put it anywhere in your css):

```
.modal-backdrop {
   opacity: 0.8 !important;
}
```

### For a Specific modal

You can eliminate the animations of a specific modal using the **windowClass** param.

```
.no-animation-modal {
  top: 25% !important;
  opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

Using windowClass:

```
var modalInstance = $modal.open({
  templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
  controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
  windowClass: 'no-animation-modal'
});
```

Comment: The border-radius of the modal top will missing when use this style.

Answer (score 0):

Don't have a full answer, but I'm having a similar issue and thought I'd chime in.  I know that this used to be possible in angular-ui/bootstrap 0.5.  There might be breaking changes in 0.6, and I'm trying to find an answer, but the documentation is pretty lacking.

[Here](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/ceb396f71652730405c7ac0d07abf16262ff88eb/src/modal/docs/demo.js) is the example given in 0.5.  Notice you can set options like `backdropFade` but I can't find the equivalent in 0.6.  Might have something to do with removing [$dialogProvider](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/ceb396f71652730405c7ac0d07abf16262ff88eb/src/dialog).

Comment: Kenjamin, you should update answer with [https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/1085] showing that it is suggested to override the HTML template in your source to make changes. For instance, I overrode the tpls example template with the same code just removing the fade class.

Answer (score 0):

The below is working well for me, whatever the `animation: false` or `animation: true`:

```
<style>
        .modal.fade {
            opacity: 1;
        }

        .modal.fade .modal-dialog, .modal.in .modal-dialog {
            -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
            -ms-transform: translate(0, 0);
            transform: translate(0, 0);
        }

        .modal-backdrop {
            opacity: 0.8 !important;
        }

</style>
```