# Disable modal animation on angular ui boostrap modal

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm using [Angular UI Bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) modal window that has a small animation when the modal window appears. The docs don't seem to have an option to disable this animation.

How can I disable that animation when modal opens?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Turn off animation, modal, angular-ui](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18873428/turn-off-animation-modal-angular-ui)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this

```
.modal.fade {
  opacity: 1;
}

.modal.fade .modal-dialog, .modal.in .modal-dialog {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate(0, 0);
  transform: translate(0, 0);
}
```

[See this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18873428/turn-off-animation-modal-angular-ui)